# How to dynamically add or subtract previous or preceding rows and get the running total?

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have vehicle odometer readings on each day, and a total odometer reading for each vehicle, a random date. I need to obtain the total odometer reading on each date based on the daily odometer readings. This involves subtracting daily readings from the total odometer reading before the total odometer reading date, and adding for anything after.

There is only 1 "Total odometer reading as of date" value per vehicle.

[image]

```
| Vehicle | Date      | Daily Odometer | Total Odometer | Expected Results |
|---------|-----------|----------------|----------------|------------------|
| A       | 01-Jan-23 | 50             |                | 10,490           |
| A       | 01-Feb-23 | 10             |                | 10,500           |
| A       | 03-Jan-23 | 0              | 10,500         | 10,500           |
| A       | 04-Jan-23 | 20             |                | 10,520           |
| B       | 01-Jan-23 | 0              |                | 7,980            |
| B       | 02-Jan-23 | 20             | 8,000          | 8,000            |
| B       | 03-Jan-23 | 40             |                | 8,040            |
| B       | 04-Jan-23 | 50             |                | 8,090            |
```

I tried to formulate this in power query, but I got stuck how the dynamic adding or subtracting based on the total odometer reading date and to show the running total for each row.

Comment: Can a vehicle have more than one 'Total as of date' reading? If so please could you update your sample above to include that.

Comment: There is only 1 "Total odometer reading as of date" value per vehicle. Updated in post, thanks.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming a table named `Reading` with the following structure:

| Vehicle | Date | Daily | TotalAsOfDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

Create a Calculated Column with:

```js
Total = 
  var fVehicle = FILTER('Reading', [Vehicle] = EARLIER([Vehicle]))
  var nTotalAsOf = CALCULATE(MAX([TotalAsOfDate]), fVehicle)
  var dDateAsOf = CALCULATE(LASTDATE('Reading'[Date]), fVehicle, 'Reading'[TotalAsOfDate] = nTotalAsOf)
  var curDate = [Date]
  var result = SWITCH(TRUE(),
    [Date] = dDateAsOf, [TotalAsOfDate],
    [Date] < dDateAsOf, nTotalAsOf -  CALCULATE(SUM('Reading'[Daily]), fVehicle, 'Reading'[Date] <= dDateAsOf && 'Reading'[Date] > curDate),
    [Date] > dDateAsOf, nTotalAsOf +  CALCULATE(SUM('Reading'[Daily]), fVehicle, 'Reading'[Date] > dDateAsOf && 'Reading'[Date] <= curDate)
  )
  RETURN result
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Powerquery (M) instead of PowerBI (DAX)

Group on vehicle
Add index column
Add column for cumulative sum of Daily Odometer using the index column
Add column that subtracts cumulative column from Total odometer column
Take max of that last column and call it StartingOdometer
Add column that adds daily odometer to StartingOdometer
Remove extra columns
Expand, done fancily here to account for any extra columns in real data

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Vehicle", type text}, {"Date", type date}, {"Daily Odometer (km)", Int64.Type}, {"Total Odometer reading as of date", Int64.Type}}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Vehicle"}, {{"data", each 
    let #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn( _, "Index", 0, 1),
    #"Added Cum Total" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "CumTotal", each List.Sum(List.FirstN(#"Added Index"[#"Daily Odometer (km)"],[Index]+1))),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Cum Total", "Custom", each try if [Total Odometer reading as of date]>0 then [Total Odometer reading as of date]-[CumTotal] else null otherwise null),
    StartingOdometer=List.Max(#"Added Custom"[Custom]),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Result", each StartingOdometer+[CumTotal]),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom1",{"Index", "CumTotal", "Custom"})
    in #"Removed Columns", type table [Date=nullable date]}}),
List = List.Difference(List.Union(List.Transform(#"Grouped Rows" [data], each Table.ColumnNames(_))),{"Vehicle"}),
#"Expanded Data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn( #"Grouped Rows", "data", List,List)
in #"Expanded Data"
```

[image]

Comment: I actually wanted to achieve this in Excel power query, and it works beautifully. However upon running both M and DAX, I found that power query runs a lot slower compared to DAX. I don't have the knowledge to say why it is so. Just my observation. Thank you